# Working with small group of developer on PHP projects

Tags: php, windows, linux, version-control

Want to work with 4-5 devs over internet on PHP projects.

**Question**: Is there any with/without central server version control system that will work with Netbeans IDE, Windows 7 and IIS?

Please: don't suggest any third-party servers like bitbucket or git-hub. I don't want to use any paid server or free ones with limited posibilities.

I want to set-up my own server. That's why asking to community

Thanks in advance.

**System specs:**
Currently My OS is: Windows 7 Ultimate X64 and IDE is Netbeans 7.1.

Comment: I'm curious what objections you have to using a 3rd party solution - especially free and secure ones. I totally understand if you want the experience of setting up the server yourself.  But maybe you are incorrect with what you believe are "limited possibilities"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer git. Since I work from a laptop, it allows me to have my own versions, while still reaping the benefits of a centralized repository.

The Windows part was answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-a-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows).

This should be the thing you're looking for, since git integrates in netbeans 7.1 REALLY well, and is easy to use and master.

Answer (score 1):

cvs and svn are both easy to setup on a server and they have clients for all the platforms mentioned.

Comment: How to install and make them public? Is there any tutorial for windows 7?

Comment: The free version of VisualSVN should be more than enough for you and is really straight-forward in setting up. http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/

Comment: @Pateman Does VisualSVN support Netbeans integration? How can I make it public?

Answer (score 1):

We are successfully using gitosis. gitolight might also be an option for small teams but I have not used it. An other option is to set up gitourious, but this might be overkill for you.

Said all that most of this systems are desigend to work on Linux. We are actually running gitosis on a Synology NAS, with 2 developers and about 30 projects.

This post might be interesting for you: [Gitosis alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557706/gitosis-alternative)

Comment: Can you help me to setup this server if I reinstall my system to ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ssh account and create a github repo that is shared among the members of the team. The limitations are negligible with this approach since you can setup a server yourself.

Take a look at http://www.mindfuzz.net/?p=250 for ideas.

Comment: "you can setup a server yourself." - which server? I'm searching for server that will work with windows 7 x64..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I decided to make this an answer after all.

VisualSVN is an easy-to-use-and-setup SVN server. Simply download the free version from http://visualsvn.com/server/download and install. Then refer to http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/ for a few tips to get you started.

You need to make sure that NetBeans supports SVN. [This link](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html) states it does.

Comment: How to make VisualSVN public? I mean how can I give access to users over internet?

Comment: Well, install VisualSVN and make sure you have the SVN port (typically 3690) open in your firewall/router/switch/etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your own server, you have many options. I personally like git, and it is quite easy to set up your own server. Check out this chapter of Progit: http://progit.org/book/ch4-0.html

It talks about your options for setting up a git server and has step by step instructions.